# std::map with key as a struct with three int members

Tags: c++, stl

I would like to use a struct with three integer members as a key. How can I overload the < operator. I understand that for two members it could be overloaded as:

```
bool operator < (const CacheKey& a, const CacheKey& b) {
    return a.x < b.x || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y);
}
```

Comment: And what is keeping you from doing the same for three members?
You just need an explicit ordering, which prevents duplicates.

Comment: They need to compare equal only when all three are equal.

Comment: Make a tuple from the members than compare that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct approach would be:

```
class Foo {
    friend bool operator<(const Foo&, const Foo&);
    int a, b, c;
}

bool operator<(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs) {
    return (lhs.a < rhs.a) || 
            (lhs.a == rhs.a && lhs.b < rhs.b) ||
            (lhs.a == rhs.a && lhs.b == rhs.b && lhs.c < rhs.c);
}
```

Comment: My bad rawrex, it was a typo. Thank you, your answer works.

Comment: @samofoz great! Best of luck!

Comment: The downside of this approach is that it requires O(n^2) code for n members.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat true! Due to being the most direct one.

Answer (score 2):

The generic solution is:

```
if (a.x != b.x) return a.x < b.x;
if (a.y != b.y) return a.y < b.y;
// ...
return false;
```

Or:

```
return std::tie(a.x, a.y) < std::tie(b.x, b.y);
```

(In this case, you might want to create a member function that returns the tied members, to be able to do something like `a.tie() < b.tie()` for all needed operators.)

Or, in C++20, you would add following to your class to automatically get all comparison operators including `<`:

```
auto operator<=>(const CacheKey &) const = default;
```